# Editing and saving PLS Playlist files

Tags: gnome, 16.04, music, totem, playlists

I've been happily making and saving playlists (in PLS format) with Totem / Gnome Video for the last few years.

But upgrading to 16.04 I find that the new totem, while it opens playlists, doesn't seem to have a way to actually visualize and edit them. Let alone save them.

At least I can't find a way to open that panel in the UI.

VLC opens but doesn't save PLS format. Rhythmbox is awkward and clunky.

So is there a way to still work with PLS files in totem? Or is there another Linux music player that's equivalent?

What I'm looking for is something simple. I don't want a program that tries to import and manage a music library. My ordinary file system is my music library. (It's over 250 gigs and it's organized the way I want ... in folders that reflect my own classification scheme.)

All I want is:

1. The ability to open a PLS file playlist
2. Change the playlist order by dragging tunes up and down
3. Drag and drop from nautilus directly into the list (at the point I want the tune to be played)
4. Be able to save the PLS file again.

Exactly as I used to be able to do in totem.

Anything like this?

Comment: Totem no longer has a sidebar & previous method of displaying/using playlists. What you may consider is xplayer which is basically the previous totem ported as an X-app by the mint guys. Works quite well though no support for grilo plugins atm. Also while it has a thumbnailer nautilus won't use so I'd leave totem installed. See here, https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/xapps

Comment: thanks. That sounds in the right direction ... just checking out Clementine now, but if that doesn't work for me then I'll try this.

Comment: yep ... that's my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two contenders for great playlist work under Linux now that Totem has 'dropped the ball' somewhat:

**1. Clementine**

Clementine, as you have mentioned is a good, easy to work with media player with *great* playlist support including the ability to edit, rearrange, export and import quite freely. The dedicated 'Playlist' tab makes it all quite easy:

[image]

Clementine has the ability to work with, both import and export, many different playlist types. You are keen on only PLS but it is nice to have some *possibilities* available. Below a screenshot of the export ability:

[image]

I have tested all of these functions under Xenial Xerus and all works perfectly...

**2. Audacious**

If you want something a little less fully 'featured' you will find that Audacious, while having less features in general, still has *excellent* playlist support. It has great shuffling, import and export, drag and drop from Nautilus, including reordering with the drag and drop, and a dedicated Playlist Editor tab:

[image]

Audacious is my own personal choice as it gets the job done with no fuss and has none of the fluff that many other players have. And from your point of view: great playlist editing support...